# Библиотека для составления диаграмм Ганта?

Tags: c++, c, 1с, планирование

Добрый день.

Какие есть свободные библиотеки для работы с диаграммами Ганта?
То есть, на ввод идут задачи, у каждой задачи предшествующая задача, время начала, крайний срок, продолжительность, какие ресурсы затрачиваются(не обязательно) и на выходе выдает данные для строительства диаграммы Ганта.

Comment: У Вас указан тег "1С". Так вот, 1С "из коробки" умеет строить диаграммы Ганта, насколько я помню. Касательно C/C++, к сожалению, ничего не могу сказать.

Comment: Нужно не рисовать их, а сформировать точки и серии для отрисовки. 
1С их только рисует из готовых данных.